# Connecting to Azure SQL database from "Execute R Script" module in "Azure Machine Learning Studio"

Tags: sql, r, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

I have already set up an **Azure SQL Database** and loaded results into it form my local machine via **R (RODBC)** successfully.  I can do queries in R Studio with no problem.

However when I use the same code in **Execute R script** module in the  ML studio, I get an error that the connection is not open.

What do I need to change? Have tried different strings for the driver with no avail.

*The reason Reader or Import Data module is not working for my case is that I am creating an API that provides me with the information to query the database before doing analytics. The database is very big and I do not want to load whole table and then use project columns, etc.*

Any help is really appreciated

Thanks all

Comment: Connection str  I am currently using in R Studio is **Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Database=xxxxxx;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxxx** and I have played around with the driver part a lot.

Answer (score 3):

RODBC in Execute R Script is not supported. You can use an Import Data (aka. Reader) module, and mark the query string as a web service parameter, if you need to dynamically inject the query.